# Access "before request load event" on Geckofx browser

Tags: geckofx

My project has user login restrictions. if the user doesn't have the authorization he can not the use any links in the GeckoFx browser. When the user clicks the link a messagebox will be shown: "You do not have access".
To work around this I need to access the "before request load event". How can this be done?

Comment: Hi. Can you explain this a little better? Are you looking for events like Load, Navigated, DocumentCompleted?